# Iterating through vue array using index

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object of some arrays. Considering the arrays have equal items, I want to iterate through these array and show their data. Does it make sense for me to iterate through index of array.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="index in someObject.listA.length">
    {{someObject.listA[index]}} - {{someObject.listB[index]}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      someObject: {
        listA: [
          'foo', 'bar', 'foobar'
        ],
        listB: [
          'foo', 'bar', 'foobar'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My main reason to ask this question is because I don't see any examples where v-for is applied using index of array. If I am doing it wrong what other options do I have to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `v-for`, the first parameter will be the element of the array, and not the index. To get the index, you have to add parenthesis and a comma.

Here:

```
<div v-for="(el, index) in someObject.listA">
```

Then you can use the index.

Answer (score 0):

[`index` is the 2nd argument in a `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

> Inside `v-for` blocks we have full access to parent scope properties.
> `v-for` also supports an optional second argument for the index of the
> current item.
>
> ```
> <ul id="example-2">
>   <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
>     {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
>   </li>
> </ul>
> ```